# JQuery: Prevent other events from being fired when a specific action is taken

Tags: jquery, event-handling

As I mentioned in the title, I would like to prevent an event from being triggered when I fire another one:

Let's take this example:

```
   $(function() {

$("#security_code").bind('change', function () {
  // Do validation and show errors
});

$("#reloadCaptcha").bind('click', function () {
  // generate new captcha and clear 'secuirity code' field

 // clear the field so the user will enter the new generated security code
  document.getElementById('security_code').value = '';
});

});
```

PURPOSE: prevent the 'change' event from being fired when the '#reloadCaptcha' is clicked.

When I click the link (second event) the first event fires too (since 'change' activates). I am looking to stop all "change" events when a link is actually clicked. I hope I was clear enough. Does anyone have any ideas?

And yes, I've tried unbind, stopPropagation and other functions from the jQuery documentation, but it just didn't work.

Note that I only want to have the "change" freezed when I click that specific link. In other cases, it should work all the time.

Thanks in advance guys! I hope there is someone out there that can clarify this for me.

Comment: Is the code inside of the click handler for the `#link_id` element changing the value of the `#username` field, and thats why the change event fires? Just looking for clarification

Comment: Yes, the code is actually inside the click handler for #link_id:  document.getElementById('security_code').value = '';

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

    $("#security_code").bind('change', function () {

        // If #security_code is empty do nothing
        if ($('#security_code').val() == '')
        {
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise validate...

    });

    $("#reloadCaptcha").bind('click', function () {

        // generate new captcha and clear 'secuirity code' field

        // clear the field so the user will enter the new generated security code
        $('#security_code').val('');

    });

});
```

Comment: It just doesn't work! it looks like the 'change' is fired before the 'click'! Thanks for all your replies guys. I can't believe this apparently tiny thing is causing me so much trouble.

Comment: this may be simple but have you tried moving your click event above your change event handling in code?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code that fires when `$("#link_id")` is clicked is changing the element `$("#username")`, the change event shouldn't fire... But either way [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) should do what you want.

Comment: Actually, it does change it. I use a refresh image link that clears a security code field. The problem is: when I click refresh a new captcha is generated and the security code field is cleared so the user can enter a new code. But when it is cleared, the change event fires and it says that the code is incorrect and it looks unprofessional.

Comment: i would have thought preventDefault() will only apply to the element within the bind() statement whereas in this case he is working across two separate elements?

Comment: Here's a new version of the code:<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function() {

$("#security_code").bind('change', function () {
  // Do validation and show errors
});

$("#reloadCaptcha").bind('click', function () {
  // generate new captcha and clear 'secuirity code' field

  document.getElementById('security_code').value = '';
});

});
//-->
</script>

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery documentation:

> To stop further handlers from
>   executing after one bound using
>   .live(), the handler must return
>   false. Calling .stopPropagation() will
>   not accomplish this.

Have you tried using .live() instead of .bind() and returning false?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing the whole code but maybe the following code would help. I know it's not a perfect solution but might help;

```
$("#username").bind('change', function () {
    if ( $('body').data('linkClicked') !== 1 )
    {
        // Validate field when element loses focus
    }
});

$("#link_id").bind('click', function () {
    $('body').data('linkClicked', 1);
    // Do something when the a specific link is clicked
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Just posted a new version of the code so you can understand better what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new version of my code:

```
$(function() {

$("#security_code").bind('change', function () {
  // Do validation and show errors
});

$("#reloadCaptcha").bind('click', function () {
  // generate new captcha and clear 'secuirity code' field

 // clear the field so the user will enter the new generated security code
  document.getElementById('security_code').value = '';
});

});
```

PURPOSE: prevent the 'change' event from being fired when the '#reloadCaptcha' is clicked.

Comment: If in your click event you're resetting the value to nothing, in your change event can't you just tell it to skip validation if value is nothing? See my 2nd answer...

Comment: Correct, but it looks like the 'change' fires before the 'click' and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/itire4/2

```
$(function() {
    $("#security_code").bind('change',function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'something') {
            $(this).bind('change');
             //do something else...
        }
    });

    $("#reloadCaptcha").bind('click',function() {
        $("#security_code").val('').unbind('change');
    });
});
```

**PS:** *the one from [timothyclifford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279204/timothyclifford) is also good.*